# Trying to create a contact form using PHP with Bluehost

Tags: php, html, forms, email, bluehost

I'm new to PHP, but I found some sample code for a web form. I adapted it like this, in a file called contact.php:

```
<?php
    mail('contact@mywebsite.com', $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message']);
?>
<p>Your message has been sent.</p>
```

and here's the HTML:

```
        <form action="contact.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
            Name<br>
            <input type="text" name="name" value=""><br><br>
            Email<br>
            <input type="text" name="email" value=""><br><br>
            Subject<br>
            <input type="text" name="subject" value=""><br><br>
            Message<br>
            <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
        </form>
```

It wasn't working, so I did some research and discovered Bluehost requires you to use their own Bluemail for this. So I ditched the PHP and followed their tutorial. That didn't work either, so I did some more research and discovered they discontinued Bluemail. So I went back to the PHP method and changed the email to a bluehost email address (apparently that's required as well).

Long story short, I checked my junk mail folder and found some of the test emails I had tried to send from the form, but they are all blank. No subject, no message content.

So it seems like the contact form is working (in that it sends an email), but the actual information inputted in the form is not coming through. I assume there's a problem with my PHP code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using wrong syntax for mail
Try

`<?php
    $msg = $_POST['name']."<br/>". $_POST['email']."<br/>". $_POST['message'];
    mail("contact@mywebsite.com",$_POST['subject'],$msg);
?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code (perhaps will work for you):

```
<?php
 $msg = $_POST['name']."<br/>". $_POST['email']."<br/>". $_POST['message'];
if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
 mail($_POST["email"],$_POST['subject'],$msg);
    echo "Your message has been sent.";    
}else{  
    echo "N0, mail is not set";
}
?>
```